# Linux: How to display the date in a different time format using the last command in terminal?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am trying to display just the time of the last logon of a user.

The goal is to display the time just like

```
date "+d% %B%t%Y"
```

would.

I tried:

```
last -n1 --time-format "+d% %B%t%Y"
```

but it keeps telling me that it is an unknown time format.
I also tried the ones in the man last examples, none of those formats seem to work. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The `--time-format` option only accepts the following options:

```
--time-format <format>  show timestamps in the specified <format>:
                               notime|short|full|iso
```

You might have to parse the datetime yourself, for example from ISO format.